# htaccess rewrite rule for url between two directories web and api

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have two separated local servers, one serves the API other servers Web.

I decided to merge them into one server, but I'm not able to distinguish the requests. My knowledge is quite limited in terms of Apache configurations, rewrite rules, etc.

Can someone help me understand or point in the right direction in how to achieve the following?

```
Directory structure:
/
/web/Index.php (handles redirects for all web page requests)
/api/Index.php (handles redirects for all api requests)

.htaccess in web/Index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Index.php [L,NC,QSA]
</IfModule>

.htaccess in api/Index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Index.php [L,NC,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I need to create .htaccess in the base directory (/) which would redirect requests to specific folder based on request URL.

```
examples:
https://example.com/api/(api-related-path) resolved by /api/Index.php
https://example.com/(something-else) resolved by /web/Index.php
```

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: So, `/api` appears in the URL, but `/web` does not? Does `Index.php` really have a capital `I`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That is what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: So you want to implement two internal rewrites: one getting applied if and only if the requested path starts with `/api/`, then other one getting applied if not. Sounds pretty straight forward considering that you already implemented rewriting rules in your prior setup.

Comment: @arkascha can you provide the working example?

Comment: It usually is far more effective if you post your best attempt, so that we can help fixing the issues you describe with it. That is what we are here for: to help, to assist, we are not here to do your work for you. Don't get that wrong: this is meant to help you learn your stuff and master your tools.

Comment: What is your actual server setup here, which directory is the document root? `https://example.com/(something-else) resolved by /web/Index.php` - for that to be the case, you would have had to set the document root to `/web`, I suppose. But then how is any request from the frontend supposed to trigger the .htaccess located in `/api` to begin with? That would be a folder located _parallel_ to the document root then, and you can not reach there via HTTP to begin with.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe for your point of view, I think that was my issue to not able redirect the requests properly between api and web. I will follow a different approach.